# fwrite binary data from a string

Tags: c++, fwrite

I would like to create a file and write "A" into it (ascii is 65 == 01000001). Strange fact, whatever the value of `std::string binary`, there is always writed the letter P in `myfile.txt`.

```
    std::string binary = "01000001";
    std::string file = "myfile.txt";
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(file.c_str(), "wb");      
    fwrite(&binary, 1, 1, f);     
    fclose(f);
```

After execution of this code, I read binary data with the command `xxd -b myfile` and I get this :

> 00000000: 01010000

Do you see a problem on this code ?

Comment: Why not use C-style strings directly? (Joke - you're not using C++ streams) You did `fopen(file.c_str()...`, but did `fwrite(&binary...`. One of them is wrong.

Comment: Do you think it could be easier to work with ofstream ?

Comment: The `binary` variable is a string that contains the ASCII representation of  "01000001". This is not a number is TEXT. To write "A" into the file you should use `binary = "A"` and then `fwrite(binary.c_str(),1,1,f)!!! But I think you would convert binary in its ASCII value starting from the binary value.

Comment: This code is a cocktail between C and C++, but solves your problem:

`#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
        std::string binary = "01000001";
        std::string file = "myfile.txt";
        char c;
        FILE* f;

        c=strtol(binary.c_str(), NULL, 2);
        f = fopen(file.c_str(), "wb");
        // fwrite(binary.c_str(),1, 1, f);     
        fwrite(&c,1, 1, f);
        fclose(f);

        return 0;
}
`

... You shall insert the right indentation!

Comment: My goal is to copy files (not only text files), I have to use binary. I guess `std::string` isn't the best way to do that. Do you have suggestions to do that without strings ?

Comment: That's working @SergioFormiggini. You should write your code into a real answer, I could give it the green light.

Comment: In C you may use a buffer to copy from a file to another using `fread(buffer,n,1,fin)` and then `fwrite(buffer,n,1,fout) where you have declared `FILE *fin, *fout`. You should cycle this two instruction while the fread instruction returns 0. In C++ you should study the ofstream and ifstream methods. I'm a C programmer then I leave you to understand how to use C++ instructions ... :)

Comment: That code is not C++ as your request indicates. Then I prefer to indicate you that your code (and also the mine) is a cocktail and a simple workaround ... But is not a professional reply (IMHO). If you reindent the code I've indicated it runs correctly.

Comment: Obviously, in the C solution, you have to declare also `char buffer[1024]; int n=1024;` (I forgot ...) ... (1024 is the buffer dimension, but may be also 10240, or other values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are bad when you want to do a bitstream...

```
int8_t binary = 0b01000001;
std::string file = "myfile.txt";
FILE* f;
f = fopen(file.c_str(), "wb");      
fwrite(&binary, 1, 1, f);     
fclose(f);
```

But when you are using C++, you don't really need to use C libraries

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream f;
    std::string file = "myfile.txt";
    f.open(file, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
    int8_t binary = 0b01000001; // int8_t is required to only write 8 bits/1 byte
    f << binary;
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `fwrite` call should be passed `&binary` instead of `binary`

Answer (score 6):

```
fwrite(&binary, 1, 1, f);
```

You pass a pointer of the  `std::string` to `fwrite`, that's bad.

You will want to get a pointer to the internal buffer of the string by calling `c_str()`:

```
fwrite(binary.c_str(), 1, 1, f);
```

This is another reason to not use C file handles, `fwrite`'s first argument is a `const void*` which is why your compiler didn't give you an error in the first place.

Comment: With his current code, this will write the character '0', not 'A' as he says he wants to write.